# how to capture the full previous command run within R?

Tags: r

i've looked at `history` and `savehistory` and `sys.call(-1)` but nothing appears to capture the full previously-executed command if that command moves onto multiple lines.  there's some r-help discussion on the topic, but i couldn't figure out a direct answer to my question.  i just want the entire previously-evaluated command captured in a character string.  is there a smart way to do this?

**edit** the purpose of this is for an R package `convey` that's dependent on another package `survey` and needs a few additional configuration commands run before usage.  if it looks like the user ran the `survey::svydesign` function immediately before the `convey::convey_prep` function, then there is no need to print the warning.  but if the user ran `survey::svydesign` and then edited the `svydesign` object prior to running `convey::convey_prep` then it could cause a mistaken calculation.  so if the command prior to `convey::convey_prep()` did not include the `svydesign()` function, then i just want to print a warning.  otherwise, it's safe to assume that the two functions were used appropriately (one-immediately-after-the-other).

i need this to work in both scripts and in interactive mode..thanks

```
# succeeds
c( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 )


hist_tf <- tempfile()
savehistory( hist_tf )
hist_lines <- readLines( hist_tf )
# this output is what i want
hist_lines[ length( hist_lines ) - 2 ]




# fails
c( 1 , 2 , 3 ,

    4 , 5 )

hist_tf <- tempfile()
savehistory( hist_tf )
hist_lines <- readLines( hist_tf )
# this output fails,
# because it does not have the `c( 1 , 2 , 3 ,`
hist_lines[ length( hist_lines ) - 2 ]
```

Comment: To be blunt, it's not a great idea to work from your history (beyond console up-arrows, anyway); it's reactive instead of proactive, so sooner or later you'll end up spending a ridiculous amount of time searching for something you should have just recorded in the first place. Instead, you should be typing your code into a file (whether a plain R script, an R Markdown script, or [an R notebook](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html)) and running it from there (by the chunk, if you like). If that's not enough for you, go Git crazy.

Comment: @alistaire no doubt.  i've edited my question to clarify my broader goal

Comment: Hmm... I'm thinking that if you want to *require* the `survey::svydesign()` function to have been run *immediately* prior to the `convey::convey_prep()` function, then maybe you could encapsulate the calling of the `survey::svydesign()` function inside `convey::convey_prep()`. This might necessitate taking some more arguments into `convey::convey_prep()` to cover `survey::svydesign()`, but it might be better both from a validation standpoint and from a usage standpoint.

Comment: @bgoldst thanks! i agree that would work code-wise but i'd prefer to keep a lighter footprint -- asking survey package users to abandon a central function and use mine instead strikes me as too heavy for a wrapper package?

Comment: thanks..  if i understand correctly, that still requires some action prior to my convey_prep function being run?

Comment: @user20650 doesn't `tracemem` still need to be run immediately on the `svydesign` object, though?  i'm not sure that it goes backwards, either?

Comment: @AnthonyDamico; yup, after re-reading your question, it is not sensible. apologies for the noise

Comment: @AnthonyDamico I agree; there are downsides to the encapsulation approach. But I've seen this design around, most often in R graphics functions. E.g. I happened to look into [`image.plot()`](https://www.image.ucar.edu/GSP/Software/Fields/Help/image.plot.html) recently, and it calls the base R `image()` and `legend()` functions internally, relaying leading variadic arguments to the former and a few named arguments to the latter. [`barplot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html) is another example, which takes a list of arguments `args.legend` for `legend()`

Comment: Looking at command history to figure this out is a terrible idea. I suggest to copy its arguments and run the `svydesign` yourself in `convey_prep` as @bgoldst suggested.